# Cmus is not playing after disabling pulseaudio and installing alsa

Tags: 13.10

I did this because i intend to play Osu! with wine, something that is very hard when there is huge amounts of latency. (I followed this guide: [The link](http://osu.ppy.sh/forum/p/1400208))

Sadly, it seems that cmus is configured for pulseAudio, so when i try to play music using it, it shows the error "Error: opening audio device: internal error".

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

We can set the output plugin cmus uses to ALSA with the following command:

```
:set output_plugin=alsa
```

Depending on our sound architecture possible values are `pulse` (default), `oss`, or `alsa`.